# Find the following integral.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Consider the $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(5x)}{2-\sqrt{3}\cos(x)} \, dx$

It's obvious that we can represent $\cos(5x)$ as sum of $\cos$ and $\sin$.

But it's also easy to see that this integral equals to coefficient of $\cos(5x)$ in Fourier transform. But how can we represent Fourier series of $\frac{1}{2-\sqrt{3} \cos(x)}$?

Comment: And this integral supposed to converge??

Comment: In fact, $\frac{\cos (5x)}{2-\sqrt3\cos x}$ is not in $\mathcal L^1[0,\infty)$ (or even in $\mathcal L^p$). Nor does the improper Riemann integral $\lim_{r\to\infty}\int_0^r\frac{\cos (5x)}{2-\sqrt3\cos x}\,dx$ exist, because the integrand is continuous, periodic and non-zero.

Comment: Related: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21406/what-is-should-be-the-right-way-for-closing-nonsensical-questions (point 1)

Comment: Well, the OP seems to be undecided between "Fourier transform" and "Fourier series". The former doesn't make sense, the latter might, if the upper limit of the integral is changed to $2\pi$. If the OP won't clarify, the question should be deleted, of course.